# Multiple EditText - specify the cursor's location

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

In my class I create two EditTexts.

```
editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText2);
```

When I start the app, the cursor is automatically put in the second EditText. How can I change to be set in the first EditText? Should I change something programmatically or in the XML?

Comment: Please upload your AndroidManiFest.xml file's code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try:

```
editText1.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 3):

there is two way of doing this one in your class like

```
   editText1.requestFocus();
```

and another in xml like

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is decided by who requests focus. Get the object, that you want to have focus and request focus and it will light up and the cursor should show up there.